# django registration redux template is not used

Tags: python, django

How do I make sure the templates in `registration` folder are used. The problem I have - `/accounts/` link is properly working but with different text (not the text I have in `registration` folder) and I can't seem to find where different text is coming from, for example this is what I have in `registration_form.html`:

```
{% extends "newsletter/base.html" %}
{% load i18n %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}


{% block content %}
<div class='row'>
<div class='col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3'>
<h1>Register for free!</h1>
<form method="post" action=".">
  {% csrf_token %}
  {{ form|crispy }}

  <input class='btn btn-block btn-primary' type="submit" value="{% trans 'Join' %}" />
</form>
</div>
</div>

<hr/>
<div class='row'>
<div class='col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3 text-align-center'>
<p>Need to <a href="{% url 'auth_login' %}">Login</a>?</p>
</div>
</div>


{% endblock %}
```

But when I enter http://127.0.0.1:8000/accounts/register/, I'm getting the following meaning my `registration_form.html` is not used at all.

[image]

As you can see, it's a completely different text from what I have. Any thoughts would be appreciated how to customize django registration redux? By the way, I tried to bring `registration` folder into `newsletter` folder (inside `templates` folder), it didn't help either. Currently I access my template files using e.g. `newsletter/base.html`, and haven't had any issues whatsoever.

My Project Folder looks like this:

```
[projectname]/                  <- project root
├── [projectname]/              <- Django root
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── settings.py
│   ├── urls.py
│   └── wsgi.py
├── newsletter/                 <-app
│   └── templates/
│       └──newsletter\          <-newsletter template
│       └──registration\        <-django-registration-redux template
│             └──registration_form.html
│             └── other django_registration-redux files
├── manage.py
├── static/
```

settings.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.sites',  # manually added
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    # third party apps
    'crispy_forms',
    'registration',  # django-registration-redux
    #  my apps
    'newsletter',
)

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

# Django-registration-redux settings
ACCOUNT_ACTIVATION_DAYS = 7
REGISTRATION_AUTO_LOGIN = True
SITE_ID = 1
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/'
```

Comment: You might find the [debug toolbar](https://github.com/django-debug-toolbar/django-debug-toolbar) helpful - it has a panel which tells you the templates used to render a page.

Comment: I have tried `http://127.0.0.1:8000/accounts/asdf` but all i can see is a couple of expected urls which I know of, but how do I know where these urls are read from e.g. `[name='auth_login']`, where is this `'auth_login`? absolutely getting desperate

Comment: I thought you wanted to know which template was used for  `/accounts/`, so why are you testing `/accounts/asdf`? It's not really clear what you're trying to do. Edit your question and add more info.

Comment: when you test incorrect url, it shows an error message and all the urls django tried to find the url from, if I type `accounts/login` it works perfectly fine, but it's not showing the files in `registration`, `django-registration-redux` must be using some other default folder. How can I make it reference to my folder?

Comment: You haven't included enough information in your question. Show your `INSTALLED_APPS` and `TEMPLATES` settings, and explain which templates you want to use and which templates are currently being used. If you use the debug toolbar, it will tell you which folder it is currently using.

Comment: Ok I will edit my question in a bit, I thought if it's a very long question people get bored even to read it...would be great if you can help out how to resolve this...cheers

Comment: Hi @Alasdair, just edited the question, any thoughts now?

Comment: It's still not clear to me which template is being used. If it's the templates from the `registration` app, then try putting `newletter` above `registration` in your `INSTALLED_APPS`.

Comment: my app is `newsletter`, and the templates are in `newsletter`>`templates`>`newsletter`. `registration` is just a template copied from `django-registration-redux`. I was following the tutorial series and that's the way they did it. I tried to swap the positions in `INSTALLED_APPS`, it seems it's doing stuff now, but I have `ImportError: No module named 'registration'`, when i migrate. (`python manage.py migrate`). Any thoughts?

Comment: sorry my mistake, i seemed to run `migrate` outside of `virtualenv`, now it's all working. Thanks a lot @Alasdair, if you want to answer the question shortly, I will accept it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [app directories templates loader](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/templates/api/#django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader) searches the `templates` directory for each app in `INSTALLED_APPS`. It stops once it finds a matching template, and uses that.

If you want to use the templates from the `newsletter` app instead of the `registration` app, then you need to move `newsletter` above `registration` in `INSTALLED_APPS`.

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    ...
    'newsletter',
    'registration',
    ...
)
```